# encapsulate text in quotes with sed buffer

Tags: regex, sed

I need to do a search and replace to encapsulate a variable string in single-quotes (php object notation into php array notation) such that the following block:

```
$my_trip->trip_id = ( $my_trips_opts->trip_id > 0 ) ? $my_trips_opts->trip_id : 1;
$my_trip->trip_name = $my_trips_opts->trip_name;
$my_trip->trip_location_paris = ( $my_trips_opts->trip_location_paris == 'paris' || $my_trips_opts->trip_location_paris == true ) ? true : false;
```

Is converted to:

```
$my_trip->trip_id = ( $my_trips_opts['trip_id'] > 0 ) ? $my_trips_opts['trip_id'] : 1;
$my_trip->trip_name = $my_trips_opts['trip_name'];
$my_trip->trip_location_paris = ( $my_trips_opts['trip_location_paris'] == 'paris' || $my_trips_opts['trip_location_paris'] == true ) ? true : false;
```

The challenge is that the string that follows "$my_trip_opts->" is variable, and likely needs to be stored in a buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not buffers: what you need are tagged regular expressions.

```
sed "s/\(\$my_trips_opts\)->\([a-zA-Z_]*\>\)/\1['\2']/g"
```

Basically, in s/patterns/replacement/, if you enclose patterns in escaped brackets, you can refer to them in the replacement by \1, \2 and so on.